# TFS Alerts for changes to work items linked to a review

Tags: tfs, linked-list, alert, review, workitem

Is it possible in TFS 2010 to create an alert when a change is made to a work item **linked** to a review work item?
I would like the reviewer to be notified of any changes made by a developer to the underlying work item to which the review work item is linked.
We are running TFS 2010 on VS 2008. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using any out of the box tools.  You can use the TFS Power Tools to create a custom work item alert, but the queries that uses to filter alerts are flat queries and you can't do any processing about their parents.

If you really want to do this you could create your own utility program. It would have to subscribe to the work item changed event and for each event check the linked work items to see if the changed work item is linked to a review item or not. If it is you can take whatever action you want to alert people that something happened, but the "alerts" would be coming from your utility, not TFS.